# Importing an .dae into Unity from blender with referenced textures

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

The issue that I'm running into revolves around 3 programs: 3DCoat, Blender, and Unity.

With 3DCoat, I export textured .obj files with their corresponding .png texture sets (textures designed for Unity). Within blender, I'll import the .obj file to convert it into a .dae file while adding additional data without altering the geometry of the object (adding points of articulation, centering, etc.). From there, I'll take the .dae and import it into Unity.

The issue comes about with the textures. From 3DCoat to blender, the .obj files reference 3 textures: the normal, the height, and the albedo. When the files are being converted to their .dae forms, some of them retain the information of referencing all 3 textures, some only reference the albedo, and a select few reference none at all. Within Blender 2.79b, I've no way of looking to see if the normal maps or height maps are being referenced unless if I export the .dae file into a completely empty folder in which the referenced textures will have a copy created in there alongside the .dae. The issue, from what I can tell, either comes from 3DCoat not referencing the textures all the time, or from blender removing references.

The reason that I'm trying to reference as opposed to just using the Materials system within Unity is by direction of higher-up co-workers of mine. That, and supposedly it saves some space within the installer.

Essentially, is there any way to fix the issue within blender, or consistently guarantee that an exported .dae will have the referenced textures?

Comment: `That, and supposedly it saves some space within the installer.` why should it? To me this seems to be not a good reason to not do it on Unity side .. just link in the according textures into the materials...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is not primarily coding related and can not be reproduced by us without having the according programs and assets.

Comment: In blender look at the [texture panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/texture_panel.html), if they are not there then most likely 3dCoat is not exporting them or is exporting them with errors. Look at blenders [console output](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/advanced/command_line/introduction.html), to see any errors while importing the objs.